# How can I use a Haskell type signature partway through an expression?

Tags: haskell

I'm doing some simple regexp work in Haskell using this [excellent tutorial](http://www.serpentine.com/blog/2007/02/27/a-haskell-regular-expression-tutorial/) as a basis, and I'm following the author's advice of using explicit type signatures to get the `=~` regexp operator to return a `String`. My problem is that I want to then manipulate this further (basically `toUpper` the result) and I can't quite see how to do this.

I've tried each of the below and with each I get a `Couldn't match expected type 'String' against inferred type 'Char'` error or similar:

```
getSKU :: FilePath -> String
getSKU path = 
    toUpper $ path =~ "^sku[0-9]{5}" :: String

-- or...
getSKU path = 
    let key = (path =~ "^sku[0-9]{5}")
    in toUpper key

-- or ...
getSKU = 
    toUpper . sub
    where
        sub p = (p =~ "^sku[0-9]{5}") :: String
```

I'm stumped - how do I express a type signature part way through an expression without resorting to a whole separate function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function `toUpper` has the signature `Char -> Char`. Use `map` to map `toUpper` over all chars in a `String`:

```
getSKU :: FilePath -> String
getSKU path = 
    map toUpper $ path =~ "^sku[0-9]{5}" :: String
```

Comment: @Alex No problem. It's easy to do mistakes in Haskell which seem obvious after a brief explanation.